# How to replace characters in a string using iteration and variables? (Python)

Tags: python, string, variables, replace, iteration

I am writing a hangman game in python as part of a college project, and I am trying to use string.replace(old, new) to substitute the blanks (_) with letters. Instead of using actual string characters though, I am trying to use variables for 'old' and 'new'. Here's what I've got so far for this bit:

```
if validGuess == 'true':
    if guess in word:
        for letter in word:
            if letter == guess:
                word.replace(letter, guess)
            else:
                missNum = (missNum + 1)
    else:
        tryNum = (tryNum - 1)
```

However, it isn't working. I don't get any errors, it simply will not replace the blanks.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to achieve what I am doing?

-**EDIT**-

I tried to implement @Peter Westlake's solution (which seemed to me the most elegant) but I have run into an issue. I have a section of code which converts a randomly selected word into underscores:

```
#converting word to underscores
wordLength = len(word)
wordLength = (wordLength - 1)
print(wordLength) #testing
for i in range(0,wordLength):
    wordGuess = (wordGuess + '_')
print(wordGuess)
```

And this seems to work fine. Here is the code for letter substitution:

```
if validGuess == 'true':
    wordGuess = ''.join([letter if guess == letter else wordGuess[pos]
                         for pos, letter in enumerate(word)])

    if guess not in word:
        tryNum = (tryNum - 1)

    print(wordGuess)
```

However, here is the output:

```
Guess a letter: a
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\Hangman\hangman.py", line 60, in <module>
    for pos, letter in enumerate(word)])
  File "G:\Python\Hangman\hangman.py", line 60, in <listcomp>
    for pos, letter in enumerate(word)])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

String index out of range? What does that mean?

Comment: i m not sure about your condition, `if letter == guess` what you need to replace here ?

Comment: can you put your input and expected output.

Comment: "String index out of range" means you are trying to get a letter from beyond the end of the string, and that's because you subtract 1 from wordLength. `range(x,y)` gives all the numbers from x to y-1, so there's no need to subtract 1 again. A simpler way to do this is: `wordGuess = '_' * len(word)`.

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace()` **returns** the new string, store the new value:

```
word = word.replace(letter, guess)
```

Python strings are immutable and cannot be altered in-place.

However, you are replacing `letter` with the exact same value; `letter == guess` is only True if both are the same character.

I'd keep a separate set of correctly guessed letters instead, and rebuild the displayed underscores and correct guesses each time:

```
correct_guesses = set()
incorrect_guesses = set()

if guess in correct_guesses & incorrect_guesses:
    print('You already guessed that letter')

elif guess in word:
    # correct guess!
    correct_guesses.add(guess)
    display_word = ''.join(char if char in correct_guesses else '_' for char in word)

else:
    # incorrect guess!
    incorrect_guesses.add(guess)
    print('Oops, incorrect guess!')
    missNum += 1
```

Comment: Just a guess because I'm not the downvoter, but: you identified a small bug in the OP's code as written, but the algorithm as a whole is wrong too, and your answer doesn't address that. It might have been better as a comment.

Comment: Hrm, I meant to come back to this post to expand. I received multiple downvotes, on more than one post, so I actually assumed a serial downvoter at work.

Comment: I have a blacklist for previously guessed letters already in a different part of the code, but I like what you've done here, I might need to think about storing the guessed letters separately...

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're getting at here.

I would probably rebuild the word-so-far on the spot instead of having a persistent string for it, keeping the tested letters separately. When the user tries a new character, make two checks:

1. See if the guess character has been guessed already: `if guess in tried`. If so, proceed however you like (penalize or ignore), but don't add the character to the tried-characters list.
2. If not, see if the character is in the target word: `elif guess in word`. If *not*, assess some penalty and add the guess to the tried-characters list.
3. For any other result: `else`. Add the guess to the tried-characters list.

To display the user's progress, make a blank string. Go through the target word character-at-a-time: `for char in word`, like you have been. But instead of trying to modify an extant string, just add the character to the end of the blank string if it's in the tried-characters string, or an underscore if not: `show += char if char in tried else "_"`. Once that `for` loop is exhausted, display what you've got!

Alternatively, use `.join` with a slightly different iterator: `show = "".join(char if char in tried else '_' for char in word)`. It'll iterate through word, keeping each letter if it's in your tried-characters string, or substituting an underscore if not, putting whatever is in `""` between them (or nothing, if you leave it as `""`). It looks like you already know that, though.

At the hazard of completely rewriting your code, this is what it might look like:

```
  ## init
word = "mauritius" # the word you're looking for. I chose this one.
tried = str()  # initialize a list of tested characters
tryNum = 3  # however many wrong guesses the user gets

  ...

  ## in your run loop...
if tryNum:  # evaluates 0 as Fasle, if you didn't already know
    guess = UserInput()  # some means to get the guess from the user; a single-character string.

    if   guess in tried:
        print "Tried that letter already!" 
    elif guess not in word:   # the letter hasn't been tested yet, but isn't in the word, either.
        print "Wrong! %d guesses left!" % tryNum
        tryNum -= 1
        tried += guess
    else:    # the guess is new (not tried) and it's valid (in the word)
        tried += guess

    show = str()  # this is the string you will display. make a blank one each time.
    for char in word:
        show += char if char in tried else "_"  # if the character has been tried, add it to the output. Otherwise, an underscore.
    print show  # display the word so far

    if show == word:
        print "You win!" # Congratulations! You hung a man.

else:  # Out of tries; the convict lives another day.
    print "Game Over!" # I am not sure how committed to this vocabulary-based execution you really are...
```

You can swap `if tryNum:` with `while tryNum:` and it should work all by itself, after initialization. If you do, there are fun things you can do with `continue`s and `break`s, but that goes a bit beyond the scope of your question.

You can swap `show = str()` and the `for char in word:` block out with the `.join` singleton in this next example, too. Change `''.join(..)` to `' '.join(..)` to add a space between characters/underscores!

This compressed version is probably a bit less Pythonic:

```
# post-init...
if tryNum:
    guess = UserInput()
    if guess in tried: pass
    elif guess not in word:
        print "Wrong! %d guesses left!" % tryNum
        tryNum -= 1
        tried  += guess
    else: tried += guess
    show = ''.join(char if char in tried else '_' for char in word)
    if show == word: print "You win!"
else: print "Game Over!"
```

This does not answer your first question of "What am I doing wrong?" but I think it might be a better way of going about what you intend? It might be a bit easier to maintain and expand for you, too.

Note: Go ahead and replace `UserInput()` with something like `str(raw_input("Guess a letter!"))[0]` if you want to try this thing out on its own.

Comment: I guess I don't have to worry too much about doing your homework, since I'm answering it ten months late... I hope some of the ideas in here are still useful to you (and future viewers), though...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Haha, yeah, this assignment has long since past! But you do have some great points in this, so thanks again -- I'm sure people looking at this in the future will find use for it. 

I managed to get the program working great in the end, I can post it up here if anybody is interested?

Comment: @James.D.Wood You can post it as an answer, sure! Just make sure you frame it as a proper answer and not just a block of working code! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a letter with an identical guess isn't going to do anything! I think you want to find the position in the word where the guessed letter appears, and replace the `_` in that position with the letter. For that you will need to find every position where the letter occurs, e.g. using the `index()` method.

For instance, to replace the first occurrence of the guess:

```
# Illustration of the principle, not the complete answer.

word = 'faq'
display = '___'

# Put in a loop, one iteration for each guess input.
guess = 'a'
display = ''.join([letter if guess == letter else display[pos]
                   for pos, letter in enumerate(word)])
print display
```

Which will print `_a_`.

Comment: I like this solution... but I can't seem to get it working the way I'd like it to. Check the OP for detail... and thanks a lot!